# Recently Created Subdomains Not Working

Tags: subdomain

Why is the subdomains not working? I created from CPanel. Can anyone helped?

```
support.sevena.com.my’s server IP address could not be found.
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Answer (score 1):

cPanel creates DNS records in its own internal DNS server, but you're using CloudFlare's instead, so cPanel's records have no effect. You'll have to create the appropriate records in CloudFlare's DNS system.